# ¿Como puedo poner centrar el titulo , los iconos de facebook , twitter gmail para que queden alineados?

Tags: html, css

Me gustaria saber como puedo centrar los iconos https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaBmg.jpg y también el titulo qya que he tenido varios problemas respecto a eso. He estado probando por mi cuenta pero no me sale , si alguien me podria ayudar le agradeceria muchisimo

```
#imagenes{
  max-width: 10%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  float: left;
}
#imagen2{
  float: left;
  max-width: 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;

}
#facebook{
  float: right;
  max-width: 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
<section class="contacto">
   <p id="titulo17">Contacto</p>
   <div id="imagenes">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/josepginer17"><img src="img/twitterlogo.png"></a>   
   </div>
   <div id="imagen2">
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#inbox"><img src="img/gmail.jpg"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/facebook.jpg"></a>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: horizontalmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acá te dejo la modificación y solución en base a tu código, espero haya solucionado tu problema :) me avisas si tienes alguna duda, saludos.

```css
.seccion{
  width: 100%; /* Acá a defines que la sección use el 100% de ancho, lo puedes cambiar a tu gusto*/
   display: inline-block; /* Acá alineas el contenido dentro de la seccion (No aplica a los div, ya que estos por defecto usan el 100% de ancho de donde están) */
}

.divTitulo{
  text-align: center; /* Acá alineas el texto del div al centro */
}

.divImagenes{
  text-align: center; /* Lo mismo, alineas las imagenes dentro del div al centro */
}

.imagen{
  heigth: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.logoGmail{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  heigth: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="seccion">
  <div class="divTitulo">
    <p>Contacto</p>
    </div>
   
    <div class="divImagenes">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/josepginer17"><img class="imagen" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/137419/isolated/preview/b1a3fab214230557053ed1c4bf17b46c-icono-de-twitter-logo-by-vexels.png"></a>   
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#inbox"><img class="imagen logoGmail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Gmail_Icon.svg/1200px-Gmail_Icon.svg.png"></a>
   
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img class="imagen" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0f/38/15/0f3815e59ec1ab026baab9cfd95eefcb.png"></a>
      </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó amigo, de nada. Saludos :)